# Use Dynamic Collection/Model for Parallel Queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

This is using Mongoose and Async

I am referencing multiple functions in an `async.parallel` call, and they basically look like this:

```
var winston = require('winston'),
    async = require('async'),
    //Mongo Models
    Product = require('../models/product'),
    Runway = require('../models/runway'),
    Conversion = require('../models/conversion'),
    Engagement = require('../models/engagement');

var user = {
    email: req.params.email
};
var score = {
    product: null,
    runway: null,
    conversion: null,
    engagement: null
};
var scoreInfo = 'email score';

findProductByID = function(id, filter, callback) {
    Product.findOne(id, filter).sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (docs !== undefined && docs !== null && docs.score !== undefined && docs.score !== null) {
            score.product = docs.score;
            console.log("Product Score for " + user.email + " : " + score.product);
            callback(null, score.product);
        } else {
            console.log("Product score not found, setting to 0");
            score.product = 0;
            callback(null, score.product);
        }
    });
};

findRunwayByID = function(id, filter, callback) {
    Runway.findOne(id, filter).sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (docs !== undefined && docs !== null && docs.score !== undefined && docs.score !== null){
            score.runway = docs.score;
            console.log("Runway Score for " + user.email + " : " + score.runway);
            callback(null, score.runway);
        } else {
            console.log("Runway score not found, setting to 0");
            score.runway = 0;
            callback(null, score.runway);
        }
    });
};

findConversionByID = function(id, filter, callback) {
    Conversion.findOne(id, filter).sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (docs !== undefined && docs !== null && docs.score !== undefined && docs.score !== null){
            score.conversion = docs.score;
            console.log("Conversion Score for " + user.email + " : " + score.conversion);
            callback(null, score.conversion);
        } else {
            console.log("Conversion score not found, setting to 0");
            score.conversion = 0;
            callback(null, score.conversion);
        }
    });
};

findEngagementByID = function(id, filter, callback) {
    Engagement.findOne(id, filter).sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (docs !== undefined && docs !== null && docs.score !== undefined && docs.score !== null){
            score.engagement = docs.score;
            console.log("Engagement Score for " + user.email + " : " + score.engagement);
            callback(null, score.engagement);
        } else {
            console.log("Engagement score not found, setting to 0");
            score.engagement = 0;
            callback(null, score.engagement);
        }
    });
};


async.parallel([
    async.apply(findProductByID, user, scoreInfo),
    async.apply(findRunwayByID, user, scoreInfo),
    async.apply(findConversionByID, user, scoreInfo),
    async.apply(findEngagementByID, user, scoreInfo),
], function(err, result) {
    res.json(score);
});
```

};

I have tried to use Square Brackets for property accessing so I can just write one function to perform 4 tasks, which looks like this:

```
findScoresByID = function(type, id, filter, callback) {
    [type].findOne(id, filter).sort({
        field: 'asc',
        _id: -1
    }).limit(1).exec(function(err, docs) {
        if (docs !== undefined && docs !== null && docs.score !== undefined && docs.score !== null){
            score[type] = docs.score;
            console.log("Score for " + user.email + " : " + score[type]);
            callback(null, score[type]);
        } else {
            console.log("Score not found, setting to 0");
            score[type] = 0;
            callback(null, score[type];
        }
    });
};

async.parallel([
    async.apply(findScoresByID, "product", user, scoreInfo),
    async.apply(findRunwayByID, "runway", user, scoreInfo),
    async.apply(findRunwayByID, "conversion", user, scoreInfo),
    async.apply(findRunwayByID, "engagement", user, scoreInfo),
], function(err, result) {
    res.json(score);
});
```

Everything in this works *except* for the second line which reads `[type].findOne...`

When I try to use this (even with a hard-coded name such as `["engagement"].findOne...` rather than the variable/argument of `[type]` ) I get an error which reads `TypeError: ["engagement"].findOne is not a function` (Also, removing the dot altogether results in a "unexpected identifier" error)

I've read previous examples on StackOverflow which seemed to use this in the way I'm intending, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you =)

Comment: Lots of tags on your question. Is this actually using mongoose? What is `type` being fed in the function? Is it a string? Is it a mongoose model? Or what exactly? You really should show your full intended usage, because there are several things you are doing here that really are not necessary.

Comment: Yes, `collectionName.findOne(...` is a mongoose function. `type` would be, in this example, `"engagement"` (so `findScoresByID("engagement",user...`. For line 2, it is specifically for a model/collection (at the top I have 4 models/collections being called - `engagement = require('../models/engagement');` being the one in question.

Comment: Dude. You're not telling me anything here. Work with the presumption that someone who is going to answer your question understands the technology better than you do. Read what I actually asked you again and make the appropriate edits to your question by showing your intended usage in it's "full context".

Comment: Edited with the most detail I can provide.

Comment: What is `user` and `scoreInfo`? Arguments to `.find()` or `.findOne()` are "query" and "projection". The projection would seem to be common, being simply return `score` since that's the only property being used. What is `field`? You you really have a document property called `field` that you want to sort on? Or is this another error where you think this is a variable? These are all the sort of things you are really expected to explain when you ask a question here.

Comment: `User` and `scoreInfo` are in the edit - `User` is the email address identifying the user, and `scoreInfo` is defining the schema fields to be returned. `Field` is a part of the `.sort()` which is saying to use the most recent `_id` field. I'm not sure how much clearer I can possibly be. The top example works, the bottom one doesn't, and the error is specifically in line 2 of the bottom one, as mentioned in my last paragraph.

Comment: Yeah well that's not actually how you code it. But at least we have some explanation of what you intended.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually have a basic mistake in your presumption of how to dynamically use the mongoose models, but there are several other things that can be cleaned up in all the code.

So first of all you don't need `asyncjs`, so just throw it away because nodejs does everything out of the box that you need it to do.

The second case is don't needlessly import models invidually for this purpose once they have allready been registered. As long as one part of the code already calls the models to register them, then we don't need the imports again here.

So presuming you named things consistently when registering the models like:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
```

Then we can just return the models by the same name they were registered with. As in:

```
Promise.all(
  ["Product","Runway","Conversion","Engagement"].map(name =>
    mongoose.model(name).findOne(
     { email: req.params.email },
     'score -_id'
    )
    .sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 })
    .then( data => ({ [name.toLowerCase()]: (data) ? data.score : 0 }) )
  )
)
.then( result => res.json(result.reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{})) )
.catch(err => console.error(err));    // Or something with error
```

Or if you are really insistent on using [`async.parallel`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) to do the same thing

```
async.parallel(
  ["Product","Runway","Conversion","Engagement"].map(name => ({
    [name.toLowerCase()]: (callback) =>  mongoose.model(name).findOne(
      { email: req.params.email },
      'score -_id'
    )
    .sort({ field: 'asc', _id: -1 })
    .exec((err,data) => {
        if (err) callback(err);
        callback(null, (data) ? data.score : 0);
      }
    )
  }))
  .reduce((acc,curr) => Object.assign(acc,curr),{}),
  (err,result) => {
    if (err) throw err; // or do something
    res.json(result);
  }
)
```

It makes the most sense to call the models by name because you want to use that same name in the output keys of the returned object ( in lowercase of course ).

Of course if you are still intent on using them, then just a small change:

```
  [Product,Runway,Conversion,Engagement].map(model => ({
    [model.name.toLowerCase()]: (callback) =>  model.findOne(
```

And that's really all there is. Similar usage without the callback return in the Promises version of course, but you should get the general idea. It also shows pretty clearly what your initial misconception of "variables" was.

The differing approaches are really only that [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) is running an array of promises produced from the list. The [`async.parallel`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#parallel) is running with an object of named keys, each provided with a wrapped function calling the result from each model.

So the response object is contructed "after" the returned results in the case of [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all), and "during" in the case of `async.parallel`. But both are essentially running the queries in "parallel".

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed response, it was quite helpful and I can see what you mean now when you commented "that's not actually how you code it." I had fallen into the bad habit of calling the models whenever they were needed, as that's how the previous code was - I will try to rectify that moving forward.

I don't currently have any follow-up questions, as your answer was quite clear; but if I do, I will be sure to reach out! Thank you again.